# how to use (useUnicode=yes characterEncoding=UTF-8 ) with DBCP

Tags: java, mysql, apache-commons-dbcp

I am trying to insert Arabic letter in to mysql database, but it only store "????". I am using DBCP for connecting with mysql databse, here is the datasource:

```
          <Resource name="jdbc/view_db" 
      auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="root" 
          password=""
          autoReconnect="true"
          testOnBorrow="true"
          validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/view_db"
          maxActive="50"
          maxIdle="10"/>
```

how to setup UTF-8 encoding with in DBCP configuration or how to use (useUnicode=yes  characterEncoding=UTF-8 ) ?

Comment: Just checking, did you specify DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 while creating your MySQL Database?

Comment: yes, I did specify CHARACTER SET utf8, it accept arabic letters when they are entered manually, however, it wont work when I am trying to insert them  from jsp file.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

According to the [DBCP documentation](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html) you need use the parameter `connectionProperties` with value `[propertyName=propertyValue;]*`, so in your case you should use something like:

```
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/view_db"
      connectionProperties="useUnicode=yes;characterEncoding=utf8;"
      maxActive="50"
```

(note the closing `;`!)

Answer (score 12):

I tried the following and it worked for me using tomcat 7.0.40 and MySQL 5.5 on Debian Wheezy box:

```
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8"
```

**Note that & must be represented as &amp;**

also make sure that your my.cnf for your mysql server has the following lines:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8
```

Answer (score 7):

Specify it in the `url` parameter, like this:

```
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/view_db?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=utf8"
```

Comment: I did it, but it said "Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at \Servers\Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config. The configuration may be corrupt or incomplete.
The reference to entity "characterEncoding" must end with the ';' delimiter." what is that means ?

Comment: You need to use &amp; in useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=utf8