# How to set oracle db connection timeout in spring Boot application

Tags: java, database, oracle, spring-boot, jdbc

I have to set Oracle DB connection timeout in Spring Boot application. How can I set it?

In WebLogic server, I am able to set using following properties:

```
oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout=50000
oracle.net.CONNECT_TIMEOUT=20000
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set it as:

```
    @Bean
    public HikariDataSource dataSource() {

        HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(springDatasourceDriverClassName);
        ds.setJdbcUrl(springDatasourceUrl);
        ds.setUsername(springDatasourceUsername);
        ds.setPassword(springDatasourcePassword);
        ds.setDataSourceProperties(oracleProperties());

        return ds;
    }

    Properties oracleProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put("oracle.net.CONNECT_TIMEOUT", 10000);
        properties.put("oracle.net.READ_TIMEOUT", 10000);
        properties.put("oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout", 10000);

        return properties;
    }
```

And if you do not want to configure a bean for the DataSource(which is what most people will do), you can configure the network timeout properties in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.oracle.net.CONNECT_TIMEOUT=10000
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.oracle.net.READ_TIMEOUT=10000
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout=10000
```

Comment: Any idea for redshift db connection timeout?

Comment: Hi @Nobita, Redshift is just PostgreSQL. This will work `spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=10000`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.timeout 5000` if you are using spring data jpa

Comment: The timeout for the application to acquire a connection(from the connection pool) has nothing to do with the JDBC/connect timeout.