# AWS Aurora Serverless RdsDataClient unicode problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-java-sdk, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm using latest AWSRDSData client for running queries on my Aurora-MySQL database.

The schema and table charsets are utf8mb4 and collation is utf8mb4_turkish_ci;

When I insert rows via MySQL workbench, there's no problem with unicode characters but when using RDS Java SDK, unicode characters such as \u015F appear as ?.

I couldn't figure out how to set charset of data client by scanning sdk methods, help is appreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20423184/750510)?

Comment: Hi @madhead rds data client gets AWS ARN as input, it's not possible to specify jdbc style connection string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved thanks to AWS support team.

Here is the point: even though the charset and collation are set on SQL Engine, the following parameters should be set in RDS DB parameter groups, in order to let rds data client understand the charset and collation for connection.
collation_server
collation_connection
character_set_server

information about parameter groups: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.how-it-works.html#aurora-serverless.parameter-groups