# Why Hibernate saveOrUpdate fails for arabic data?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, netbeans, arabic

When I save arabic string, the result in the database `MySQL` is simply `?`.

In the table structure the encoding of the column is `UTF-8`, there are other arabic data, which means the problem is coming from `Hibernate 4.3`, when I looked at the documentation `Developer Guide` there is only one subject related to encoding, UTF, Arabic..,  they suggested puting `@Nationalized` annotation, I did that and it is not useful.

By debugging, the arabic string is still in the object until:

```
session.saveOrUpdate(myObj);
```

After that I dont know what happened.

I am developing on `Netbeans`, thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put below line in datasource by specifying `useUnicode` and `characterEncoding`.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

If you are using spring boot put below line in application.properties file.

```
spring.datasource.connectionProperties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;
```

See [use-useunicode-yes-characterencoding-utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359683/how-to-use-useunicode-yes-characterencoding-utf-8-with-dbcp/13360206)

Comment: Thank you, now my url is: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull`

Answer (score 0):

you must specify charset for schema and table, just change your default charset of database, base on following below link :

[Change MySQL default character set to UTF-8 in my.cnf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf-8-in-my-cnf)

if you read this link and change setting you must :

**first :**  restart mysql or any other like this (systemctl start mysql)

**second :** drop your schema and database and tables then recreate it.

This work for persian language.